# apt update VS apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu, apt

For years, I was always under the impression that results of `apt update` and `apt-get update` are identical.
BTW - Yes, I am aware `apt` and `apt-get` are not exactly the same.

I recently noticed that once I run `apt update` on my Ubuntu box, it checks with 13 sources, but `apt-get update` only checks with 7 sources. Also, there are total 7 update sources listed under `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

I was not able to find any information about this online. Does anyone around have any explanation for me?

***EDIT
Here is a similar output from my Mint box. It is showing the same behavior. I probably missing something, but not sure what it is.

```
pcko@MBP12:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for pcko:     
Ign:1 http://packages.linuxmint.com una InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.linuxmint.com una Release                                
Hit:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease              
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,745 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [277 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [918 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40.6 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [390 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [66.3 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,980 B]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [30.8 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Fetched 3,816 kB in 2s (1,574 kB/s)                                          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
211 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

pcko@MBP12:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://packages.linuxmint.com una InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.linuxmint.com una Release                                                                                                              
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                              
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                       
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                             
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                          
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease               
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

pcko@MBP12:~$ cd /etc/apt
pcko@MBP12:/etc/apt$ ls
apt.conf.d  auth.conf.d  preferences.d  sources.list  sources.list.d  trusted.gpg.d

pcko@MBP12:/etc/apt$ cat sources.list
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 20.3 _Una_ - Release amd64 20220104]/ focal contrib main

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.

pcko@MBP12:/etc/apt$ cd sources.list.d/
pcko@MBP12:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls
official-package-repositories.list  vscode.list

pcko@MBP12:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ cat official-package-repositories.list 
# Do not edit this file manually, use Software Sources instead.

deb http://packages.linuxmint.com una main upstream import backport #id:linuxmint_main

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner

pcko@MBP12:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ cat vscode.list 
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
```

Comment: apt is a subset of apt-get and also easier due to its fewer options as well as better CLI.

Comment: @Roi that's as maybe but doesn't address the interesting question posed here

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to answer this.  Please edit your question and add the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` files, and sample output of `apt update` and `apt-get update`.  Copy and paste the **text** from your terminal, [do not post a screenshot](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: Note that apt doesn't do a full check if it finds that the existing information is up-to-date (I don't recall the exact mechanism of the check, probably timestamps provided by headers). Anyway, if you tried this multiple times, but change the order, you'll find that often the first command to run will download more files, no matter which one it was.

Comment: @muru, yep, that's exactly it.  The second update checks the InRelease files, sees that they haven't changed since the last update, so doesn't need to download any other repo files.

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I agree that @muru's comment is accurate:

> Note that apt doesn't do a full check if it finds that the existing information is up-to-date (I don't recall the exact mechanism of the check, probably timestamps provided by headers). Anyway, if you tried this multiple times, but change the order, you'll find that often the first command to run will download more files, no matter which one it was.